# How to redirect UIWebview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

I am new to iPhone development and I want to move to `UIWebview` based on the URL when the user clicks on a particular row (Google,Facebook,Yahoo). I want the page to redirect to the UIWebview.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"]];
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        //What do i write in here
    } else if(indexPath.row == 1) {

    } else if(indexPath.row == 2) {

    } else {

    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is UIWebView controlled by the same view controller? If it is not, than you should perform a segue to another ViewController that manages a UIWebView, and pass a link there.

Comment: can you please show me some sample code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to create a new controller and navigate to that controller on click. Also you have to pass link to another controller for load the url in to webview.

Comment: I would like to add that if you want a good example of passing parameters between ViewControllers and segue management you can check out this tutorial http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/

Answer (score 0):

If a webView is managed by the same ViewController (so the ViewController has a property like this):

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView;
```

then you can open a link like so:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://your-url-goes-here.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

However if the webView is managed by another ViewController than you have to pass a link to that ViewController and then trigger a segue.
A common approach is to set viewController's property to pass a link.

For example in WebViewController.h

```
...
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *linkToOpen; //My fantasy isn't really working right now :)
...
```

in WebViewController.m

```
...
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:self.linkToOpen] autorelease];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}
...
```

And a segue from your ViewController to the WebViewController has an identifer @"myTestSegue" then you can do it like so:

```
WebViewController *webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithStyle:/*I don't honestly remember what to write here, sorry :(*/];
webViewController.linkToOpen = @"your link goes here. You can assign it inside a switch operator.";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
[webViewController release];
```

The code is incomplete and probably incorrect somewhere, but I hope that it will help you to achieve your goals.